# Angucomplete Alt url remote

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

i use Angucomplete Alt directive for making autocomplete.
it work fine till now , but i want to make a specific request to my server.
/search/users/name?s=

```
<div angucomplete-alt
             id="input-name"
             placeholder="Name"
             pause="50"
             search-fields="name"
             remote-url=/users/name?s=
             title-field="name"
             minlength="3"
             match-class="angucomplete-match">
        </div>
```

In Other word, i want to change all spaces to dot before sending the Request to my Server.

Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the remote-api-handle option to modify the string before it gets sent to the server.

```
<div angucomplete-alt
         id="input-name"
         placeholder="Name"
         pause="50"
         search-fields="name"
         remote-url-handler="searchAPI"
         title-field="name"
         minlength="3"
         match-class="angucomplete-match">
    </div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.searchAPI = function(userInputString, timeoutPromise) {
  //Modify input before it gets sent to the server
  userInputString = userInputString.replace(' ', '.');
  return $http.post('/users/name', {s: userInputString}, {timeout: timeoutPromise});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use remote-api-handler:

```
<angucomplete-alt
             id="input-name"
             placeholder="Name"
             pause="50"
             search-fields="name"
             remote-api-handler="searchAPI"
             title-field="name"
             minlength="3"
             match-class="angucomplete-match" />
```